# How to call big hqls files via sqlContext?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I am currently exploring how to call big hql files (contains 100 line of an insert into select statement) via `sqlContext`.

Another thing is, The `hqls` files are parameterize, so while calling it from `sqlContext`, I want to pass the parameters as well.

Have gone through loads of blogs and posts, but not found any answers to this.

Another thing I was trying, to store an output of `rdd` into a variable.

pyspark

```
max_date=sqlContext.sql("select count(rec_insert_date) from table")
```

now want to pass `max_date` as variable to next `rdd`

```
incremetal_data=sqlConext.sql(s"select count(1) from table2 where rec_insert_date > $max_date")
```

But above code is not working.